# jqGrid about send more request

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When I used `jqGrid` sending a request to research the database and reloading the grid, I found it sent two requests (printing two SQLs in the console) using codes below:

```
$("#gridtable").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    url : url + searchName + searchContent,
    page : 1,
}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`setGridParam`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) states (emphasis mine):

> Sets a particular parameter. Note - for **some** parameters to take effect a trigger(“reloadGrid”) should be executed.

The [options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) page does not state that either `url` or `page` require a reload. Try removing the code `.trigger("reloadGrid")` and see if your code still makes two requests.

Comment: Thanks all the time.I have removed it .It`s already one request,but the grid doesn`t reload any more